# decimal to binary conversion in matlab

Tags: matlab

the conversion of decimal to binary of text derived from a file is

```
temp=textread('E:\one.txt', '%1s', 'whitespace', '');  
text = char(temp);                                                           
y = zeros(length(text)*8,1);                                           
for n = 1:1:length(text)  
a=abs(text(n));                                                              
f = 8*(n-1)+1;                                                          
y(f:f+7,1)=(de2bi(a,8))';                                                   
end
disp('THE MAGNITUDE OF THE TEXT IS =');
disp(a);
disp(f);
x=y';
disp('THE BINARY BITS ARE');
disp(x);
```

output of this program if file contained '1' stored in it

```
THE MAGNITUDE OF THE TEXT IS =
49

 1

THE BINARY BITS ARE
 1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
```

if the number of bit of x is 8bit then i want first 3 bits displayed in a variable and rest 5 bits in another variable 
i want a program for this in matlab.

```
eg x=00110011
a=001
b=10011
```

encoding program

```
clc;
clear all;
temp=textread('E:\one.txt', '%1s', 'whitespace', '');  
text = char(temp);                                                               
y = zeros(length(text)*8,1);                                                
for n = 1:1:length(text)  
    a=abs(text(n));                                                                 
    f = 8*(n-1)+1;                                                                    
    y(f:f+7,1)=(de2bi(a,8))';                                            
end
disp('THE MAGNITUDE OF THE TEXT IS =');
disp(a);
disp(f);
x=y';
disp('THE BINARY BITS ARE');
disp(x);
z=length(x);
savefile='D:\mat\z.mat';
save (savefile,'z','-MAT');
disp('TOTAL NUMBER OF BITS =');
disp(z);
bk=input('ENTER THE NUMBER OF ROWS =');
savefile='D:\mat\bk.mat';
save (savefile,'bk','-MAT');
c=z/bk;
savefile='D:\mat\c.mat';
save (savefile,'c','-MAT');
k=1;
for i=1:bk
    for j=1:c
        m(i,j)=x(k);
        k=k+1;
    end
end
%disp(m(i,j));
disp('THE MESSAGE BITS ARE ');
disp(m);
savefile='D:\mat\m.mat';
save (savefile,'m','-MAT');
m_tot=(size(m,1)*size(m,2));
savefile='D:\mat\m_tot.mat';
save (savefile,'m_tot','-MAT');
savefile='D:\mat\r1.mat';
r1=[randperm(bk),randperm(bk)];
save (savefile,'r1','-MAT');
disp(r1);
savefile='D:\mat\r2.mat';
r2=[randperm(bk),randperm(bk)];
save (savefile,'r2','-MAT');
disp(r2);
savefile='D:\mat\f(1).mat';
f1= randint(1,1,[1,bk]);
save (savefile,'f1','-MAT');
savefile='D:\mat\en.mat';
en(1,:)=m(f1,:);
save (savefile,'en','-MAT');
disp('DIRECTLY ASSIGNED BLOCK IS');
disp(f1);
for w=1:(length(r1))
    en(w+1,:)=xor((m(r1(w),:)),(m(r2(w),:)));
    disp('THE EXORED BLOCKS ARE= ');
    disp(r1(w));
    disp(r2(w));
end
disp('THE ENCODED BITS ARE');
disp(en);
en_tot=(size(en,1)*size(en,2));
disp('tot no of encoded bits');
disp(en_tot);
save (savefile,'en_tot','-MAT');
savefile='D:\mat\en_tot.mat';
```

the variable en should be split based on hop count same as u did with variable x.

Comment: What is this program supposed to compute? Could you give a sample i/p and o/p?

Comment: this program reads a text or numeric from text file named 'one ' in E drive and displays the binary bits .

Comment: from the o/p i need to display a paticular number of bits from x . say if the user wants only first 3 bits , it should display first 3 bits of x and also if user wants 2 display last 4 bits. it shoud be dynamic from user how many bits he/she wants from x

Comment: So x is just a number array? How about x(1:3) and x(4:end)?

Comment: So is that your entire question?

Comment: i need it dynamic from d user and display it

Comment: for transmitting information from source node  to destination node in wireless sensor network , i need to encode the information then transmit . if there are three paths to destination from source, i need to split the information  according to hop count in each path. hence converting info into binary , then divide this binary into part according to hop count in each path. the info must not be same in any path.

Comment: so if information converted to binary stored in variable say x. if there are 3 paths to destination from source , and hop count 3,2 & 3 .if x is 16bits. by dividing length of x with total number of count ((16/8)=2). hence first 6 bit ( hop count * (16/8)) should be sent through 1st path , then next 4 bits of x sent through 2nd path and last 6 bits through 3rd path. hence with help of number of bits and hop count known , i needed to divide the bits. but i needed it all dynamic from user including hop count

Comment: can u help me with this ? this is my actual question

Comment: Give me a few minutes. Let me take a look.

Comment: I've added some new code; I hope it'll be of some help.

Comment: De nada. Happy to help. :)

Comment: hi i have posted another question , can u help me with tat ?

Comment: i have posted the program here in this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a new question. This is the same problem as before. As such, for your own sake, I'm going to have to decline. Try going through the code from before and try to understand how it works; once you do that, you'll be able to modify it as required. You can always try me (or SO in general, of course) for doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
%After computing "x", the double array, as required...
d = input('Enter the length of the first sub-array: ');
a = x(1:d)
b = x(d+1:end)
```

For example:

```
>> 
temp='1';  
text = char(temp);                                                           
y = zeros(length(text)*8,1);                                           
for n = 1:1:length(text)  
a=abs(text(n));                                                              
f = 8*(n-1)+1;                                                          
y(f:f+7,1)=(de2bi(a,8))';                                                   
end
disp('THE MAGNITUDE OF THE TEXT IS =');
disp(a);
disp(f);
x=y';
disp('THE BINARY BITS ARE');
disp(x);
%After computing "x", the double array, as required...
d = input('Enter the length of the first sub-array: ');
a = x(1:d)
b = x(d+1:end)
```

The result would be:

```
THE MAGNITUDE OF THE TEXT IS =
    49

     1

THE BINARY BITS ARE
     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0

Enter the length of the first sub-array: 3

a =

     1     0     0


b =

     0     1     1     0     0
```

I'm still unsure as to what this program is supposed to achieve though.

### **EDIT**

New code as per changed requirement:

```
>> 
temp='1';  
text = char(temp);                                                           
y = zeros(length(text)*8,1);                                           
for n = 1:1:length(text)  
    a=abs(text(n));                                                              
    f = 8*(n-1)+1;                                                          
    y(f:f+7,1)=(de2bi(a,8))';                                                   
end
disp('THE MAGNITUDE OF THE TEXT IS =');
disp(a);
disp(f);
x=y';
disp('THE BINARY BITS ARE');
disp(x);
%After computing "x", the double array, as required...
d = input('Enter the hop-count vector: ');
for i=2:length(d)
    d(i) = d(i) + d(i-1);
end
d = [0, ceil((d./d(end))*length(x))];
disp('The resultant split up is:')
for i=2:length(d)
    disp(x((d(i-1)+1):d(i)));
end
```

The result will be:

```
THE MAGNITUDE OF THE TEXT IS =
    49

     1

THE BINARY BITS ARE
     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0

Enter the hop-count vector: [3 2 3]
The resultant split up is:
     1     0     0

     0     1

     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just slice the array:

```
disp(x(1:3));
disp(x(4:end));
```